# make select query condition relative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

First table tblCPWgts,

```
       cp nvarchar(10)
       cDate date
       weight float
```

Second table tblCP

```
       cp nvarchar(20)
       code nvarchar(5)
```

I currently have a query like below

```
 select * from
 (
    select cp, cDate, weight from tblCPWgts where cDate >= '2014-09-09'
 )source pivot(max(weight) for cp in ([AB], [CD], [EF]) as pvt order by cDate
```

this works fine. However the number of cp's will change in the future. So rather than hard code them in like above ([AB], [CD], [EF]) I would like to make use of the table tblCP where the column code has AB, CD, EF.

Is there anyway to adjust my query above so that it doesn't need the cp's hard coded? I tried below but after writing it realised it obviously won't work but that is what I'm trying to do.

```
select * from
 (
    select cp, cDate, weight from tblCPWgts where cDate >= '2014-09-09'
 )source pivot(max(weight) for cp in (select code from tblCP) as pvt order by cDate
```

Comment: You need to build a dynamic query and use `exec()`

Comment: I see, how do i do that though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the codes into a variable and then use it to build your dynamic query.

```
declare @codes nvarchar(max) = ''

select @codes = @codes + '[' + code + '], '
from tblCP

set @codes = SUBSTRING(@codes, 1, LEN(@codes) - 1)

declare @q nvarchar(max)

set @q = 'select * from
 (
    select cp, cDate, weight from tblCPWgts where cDate >= ''2014-09-09''
 )source pivot(max(weight) for cp in (' + @codes + ') as pvt order by cDate'

exec(@q)
```

Comment: I'm getting an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

Answer (score 2):

try this dynamic query.

```
            DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @code AS VARCHAR (MAX)


            SELECT @code =
            COALESCE(@code + ', ','')+ QUOTENAME(code)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT distinct code from tblCP 

            ) AS B


            SET @SQL = '
            select * from
             (
                select cp, cDate, weight from tblCPWgts where 
                cDate >= ''2014-09-09''
             )source 

             pivot
             (max(weight) 

             for cp in (  '+@code+') 

             as pvt order by cDate'

            print (@SQL)

            EXEC  (@SQL)
```